# Cloudfront prevent caching whole site

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, prestashop, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I want use Cloudfront for caching jpg, png, css, js files from a Prestashop website (domain.com) and get a fastest website.
I setup this configuration:

I create a distribution in Amazon CloudFront with origin domain.com and alternate domain name static.domain.com

Domain.com = Prestashop website
static.domain.com -> CNAME -> xxx.cloudfront.net (Provided from CF)

Now, when i load "static.domain.com" load a WHOLE site "domain.com". This is bad for SEO and will be expensive caching whole site.

I want to optimize and configure correctly CF for:

1. Catching only certain files
2. Prevent unnecessary expenses

I try to configure behavior, but always load the whole site.
Where can I configure the files to cache?
Can someone help me please?
Thanks u and regards

Answer (score 1):

You can create additional [Behaviours](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesCacheBehavior) for your CloudFront distribution. On each behaviour you can set a path patterns, example: `images/*.jpg`. This means, that the behaviour will apply only to paths which requesting certain images from your origin.

Every CloudFront distribution has a default behaviour, which has the path patter of `*` (cache everything). You can disable that by setting the cache policy to: `Managed - CachingDisabled` (see: [disable caching for certain files](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/prevent-cloudfront-from-caching-files/#:%7E:text=On%20your%20custom%20origin%20web,t%20want%20CloudFront%20to%20cache)).

Comment: Yes, i tried but when i access to static.domain.com, but the website load full, i want only access to certain files, not only caching, too serving.
I would like you to generate a 500 error when you try to access a file that is not allowed (jpg, png, js, css, ...)